# Can I find numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a=2b$?

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to know if it's possible to find two numbers $a$ and $b$ with 8 digits each using these ones : $2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9$, such that $a=2b$.

I don't know how to begin to attack this problem. Which tools can I use to solve this question?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible.

If $a=2b$, then $3$ would be a divisor of $a+b$. Basically, when I encounter a question involving the digits of a natural number I immediately think of divisibility by $3$. Recall that a number is divisible by $3$ if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by $3$. Modulo $3$, the sum of digits of $a+b$ is $2+2+3+3+4+4+\cdots+9+9=88$, which is not a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 2):

No. The sum of the availabvle digits is $88$. The sum of digits of $b$ is concruent $b\pmod 3$, the sum of thos of $a$ is congriuent $2b\pmod 3$, hence the sum of all digits should be $\equiv 3b\equiv 0\pmod 3$.